# Get values for parameters from remote API in cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

We have a remote API (not AWS) from which we can read values for parameters.
Can we read those values in cloudformation and use them as values?

Or is the only possible way to get the values and provide them by using the `aws cli` and passing the values as values of parameters in a deploy commmand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the cloudformation [custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html) to call a lambda function parse the API output and send it back to cloudformation and get it via `!GetAtt`

Cloudformation:

```
    Resources:
      API:
        Type: Custom::API
        Version: '1.0'
        Properties:
          ServiceToken: arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:acc:function:CALL_API
    Outputs:
      Status:
        Value:
          Fn::GetAtt:
          - API
          - Data
```

Lambda Script:

```
import json
import cfnresponse
import boto3
import urllib.request 
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

def handler(event, context):
    responseData = {}
    try:
        with urllib.request.urlopen("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=google") as url:
            data = json.loads(url.read().decode())
        print(data)
        responseData['Data'] = data
        status=cfnresponse.SUCCESS
    except ClientError as e:
        responseData['Data'] = "FAILED"
        status=cfnresponse.FAILED
        print("Unexpected error: %s" % e)
    cfnresponse.send(event, context, status, responseData, "CustomResourcePhysicalID")
```

Comment: The function seems to work, It's SUCCESS and I see the json output in cloudwatch but when I want to access that json with !GetAtt API.Data I get: Template format error: Every Value member must be a string.

Comment: How do you use the GetAtt? you might need to modify the script to send it as a string instead of json,